# Push notifications with custom sounds not showing up in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

custom push notifications done with firebase cloud functions work perfectly with android but doesn't work with iOS.

I have tried placing the custom sound in the Runner folder, as seen on multiple tutorials online. its a .wav file.

my cloud function payload is setup like this :

```
var payload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": msgData.name +" Needs Your Help!",
                "body": "new Alert Message: "+msgData.job_type,
                "sound": "submarine.wav"
            },
```

on android the notification works, but on ios it doesnt even show a notification. if it turn sound to Default, it works but it simply doesnt play the custom submarine.wav file

Comment: Have you imported the sound file to your project, made sure it is included in the bundle and also linked it to the correct target?

Comment: @BrandonStillitano I have done all of this and still it doesnt work. is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I have even converted the file to .CAF . I have no other solutions to this...

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a message for both iOS and Android you have to set aps settings as well. See guide below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages?authuser=0#ApnsConfig

```
payload = {
    notification:{
        title: 'Notification title goes here',
        body: 'Body of notification goes here',
    },
    android: {
    },
    apns: {
        headers:{
            "apns-collapse-id": "id_here",
            "content-available": "1",
            "apns-priority": "10",
        },
        payload:{
            aps:{
                sound: 'default'
            }
        }
    },
    data:{
        type: 'type'
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this but how come it works perfectly with the default sound?. also, the `apns-collapse-id` is the app id ?

Comment: I found the solution! some how i forgot to check permissions like so : `_messaging.requestNotificationPermissions()`

Comment: @SkyentGroup no it is the Id that groups the messages together. Useful if notifications are from the same message thread etc

Comment: this solution will not work for cloud functions. here is there error they show : `Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "apns" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".`